# Selenium Python Invalid Column Error message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code which I use to open the new tab using Selenium Python,

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])", self.listing_url)
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(10)
```

and it works perfectly. But I am planning to use WebDriverWait instead of time.sleep

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])", self.listing_url)
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="honbun"]')))
```

and when I am using it, it's throwing an error. Here is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\tender_scraper\engine\Spider.py", line 308, in parse_index_page
    index_handle = self.load_listing_page(listing, i, index_listing)
  File "D:\tender_scraper\spiders\gunmapref_listing_spider.py", line 298, in load_listing_page
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="honbun"]')))
  File "D:\scraper\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 78, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "D:\scraper\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 64, in _predicate
    return driver.find_element(*locator)
  File "D:\scraper\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\scraper\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\scraper\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: missing or invalid columnNumber
  (Session info: headless chrome=104.0.5112.48)
```

Any idea what's wrong with it & how to solve it? Previously, I used chrome 103 and changed it to 104 but still got the same error. It seems the error only occurs when changing into the new tab.